# SharpDX 3 loading .DDS to apply onto a 3d model (C#)

Tags: c#, directx-11, bmp, sharpdx

I'm attempting to create a model viewer for a game to try and learn SharpDX but the game uses .DDS files and the viewer can only read .BMPs. I've looked far and wide on the webs and the only things I can find are load them but don't seem to work for SharpDX (I don't know im a noob :D)

```
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.WIC;

namespace ModelViewer.Programming.GraphicClasses
{
    public class TextureClass
    {
        public ShaderResourceView TextureResource { get; private set; }
        public bool Init(Device device, string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var texture = LoadFromFile(device, new ImagingFactory(), fileName))
                {
                    ShaderResourceViewDescription srvDesc = new ShaderResourceViewDescription()
                    {
                        Format = texture.Description.Format,
                        Dimension = SharpDX.Direct3D.ShaderResourceViewDimension.Texture2D,
                    };
                    srvDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
                    srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = -1;

                    TextureResource = new ShaderResourceView(device, texture, srvDesc);
                    device.ImmediateContext.GenerateMips(TextureResource);
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }        
        public void Shutdown()
        {
            TextureResource?.Dispose();
            TextureResource = null;
        }
        public Texture2D LoadFromFile(Device device, ImagingFactory factory, string fileName)
        {
            using (var bs = LoadBitmap(factory, fileName))
                return CreateTextureFromBitmap(device, bs);
        }
        public BitmapSource LoadBitmap(ImagingFactory factory, string filename)
        {
            var bitmapDecoder = new BitmapDecoder(factory, filename, DecodeOptions.CacheOnDemand);
            var result = new FormatConverter(factory);
            result.Initialize(bitmapDecoder.GetFrame(0), SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppPRGBA, BitmapDitherType.None, null, 0.0, BitmapPaletteType.Custom);
            return result;
        }
        public Texture2D CreateTextureFromBitmap(Device device, BitmapSource bitmapSource)
        {
            int stride = bitmapSource.Size.Width * 4;
            using (var buffer = new SharpDX.DataStream(bitmapSource.Size.Height * stride, true, true))
            {
                bitmapSource.CopyPixels(stride, buffer);
                return new Texture2D(device, new Texture2DDescription()
                {
                    Width = bitmapSource.Size.Width,
                    Height = bitmapSource.Size.Height,
                    ArraySize = 1,
                    BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource | BindFlags.RenderTarget,
                    Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
                    CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
                    Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
                    MipLevels = 1,
                    OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.GenerateMipMaps,
                    SampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
                },
                new SharpDX.DataRectangle(buffer.DataPointer, stride));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have a feeling this will need to be completely redone to utilize the DDS format. Is it easier to simply read one and then convert it to a bitmap?